# How can use math().by() in gremlin while two point has diffrent column name?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I have a graph in janusgrah that has two point,

```
order:id,channel,order_time  
shipments:id,channel,ship_time
```

how can I realize sql like this  using Gremlin  grammar?

```
select channel,avg (ship_time - order_time)  from order join shipments 
using(id) group by channel
```

I try to write as

```
g.V().has('Type', 
textContains('order').as('a').out('shipment').as('b').math('a'- 
'b').by('???').groupCount().by('channel')
```

and I don't know how to write the parameter in math().by("???") when the column name is different.

Answer (score 1):

You just use 2 `by()` modulators.

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').as('a').
           outE().as('b').
           math('a*b').
             by('age').
             by('weight')
==>11.600000000000001
==>14.5
==>29.0
==>32.0
==>12.8
==>7.0
```

Comment: thank you .now I meet another problem,order_time and ship_time  are both String type.so it throws the exception as,     
  
     " java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number".

how can I cast order_time  and ship_time to int  when using by('order_time').by('ship_time')?

Comment: Casting can only be done using lambdas, which is one reason why you should store the properties as numbers in the first place. The other reason is, obviously, the performance impact. However, if it's just for a quick test, you can do `...by {Long.parseLong(it.value('order_time))}` (or whatever is needed to convert these strings into numbers, e.g. parse them as date and return the epoch seconds; it all depends on which format you're using).